# vim replacement issue

Tags: vim

I have some lines like below:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

I want them to be changed like this:

```
aaa=$aaa
bbb=$bbb
ccc=$ccc
ddd=$ddd
```

so I use the following command to do it in vim, but I got an error

```
:s/\(\^*\)/\1=\$\1/
```

and I realized the `\1` here could not be used twice, then how should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back reference `\1` can be used as many times as you wish, but you have another problem. Your regex should look like that:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)/\1=\$\1/
```

Explanation: the `%` tells vim to replace on all lines; `^` as a mark for the beginning of line should be the first character in your regex and should not be escaped. The `.*` means "any character any number of times". However, the original expression `\(\^*\)` will look for any number of repeats of the literal character `^` (including none).

Answer (score 4):

When matching the entire contents of the line, you neither need the `^` anchor, nor the capture via `\(...\)`. In the replacement, you can use `\0` or shorter `&`. (Also, you don't need to escape the `$` there.)

```
:%s/.*/&=$&
```